# Why do I get an error using moveTo in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I am opening a new window from a button using var myWindow = window.open(...). I then want to move that window to the correct location on the screen. I use myWindow.moveTo(10,10) to do this but I get an Access Denied error.

The window I open contains information from another server to the one I am executing on. When it isn't, the window moves correctly. Is this the limitation and is there a way around it?

I am using IE7. (The work is for an existing Intranet that includes lots of ActiveX so all users use IE7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to put the information from the other site in an iframe located on the same host that runs the window.open JavaScript. Or maybe even better, get the information server-side and present it directly from your site. Iframes can be trouble.

Answer (score 1):

> The window I open contains information from another server to the one I am executing on. When it isn't, the window moves correctly. Is this the limitation and is there a way around it?

Browsers security model have been increasingly restrictive over the last couple of years. What you could do a few years ago, isn't allowed any more. Blame it on advertising companies.

Comment: Is there a way around it though? With IE configuration?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the "Same Origin Policy" in action (Google that). You can change the clients configuration to lax on security, if you have access to them.